# How do I create a class with the same name as another class/interface?

Tags: dart

I want to create my own class named Point, but am running into issues with the interface of the same name in the html library. What am I missing that would get me out of the "already defined as interface" pickle?

```
class Point
{
//r is x
// g is the difference between x+y and 0
// b is y
  num r,g,b;
  Point(this.r, this.g, this.b);
...
}
```

> Internal error:
>   'http://127.0.0.1:3030/C:/Users/.../Desktop/dart/workspace/projects/.../Point.dart': error: line 1 pos 7: 'Point' is already defined as interface class
>   Point

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicate Class in Dart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262297/duplicate-class-in-dart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When importing the library that has the class/interface you want to reuse, qualify it with a prefix, which will force you to be explicit to use the original class, and will use the new class implicitly.

```
#import('dart:html', prefix:'html');
```

`html.Point` will use the point interface in html.
`Point` will use the class in your project/library.

Comment: Note that this exact question was already asked (and answered), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262297/duplicate-class-in-dart/

Comment: @ladicek no dispute there. it did not show up when asking this question, nor when googling.